# "self" in python lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

```
def buildTestCase(xmlfile, description, method, evalString):
  func = lambda self, xmlfile=xmlfile, method=method, evalString=evalString: \
       method(self, evalString, feedparser.parse(xmlfile))  
  func.__doc__ = description
  return func
```

Above is a code snippet from feedparser, why there is a "self" in function definition method(self, evalString, feedparser.parse(xmlfile))?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`self`simply refers to the first argument of the lambda named `self`.

the name `self` is not a reserved keyword, it is merely a convention above pythonistas to name the instance of the object on which the function applies. here, the author uses the name `self` as the first argument to the lambda, because this argument will receive an instance of an object on which the lambda will apply the method specified in the argument named `method`.

Answer (score 3):

Methods can be called via their class by passing an instance of the class as the first argument. Since the first argument of a normal method is called `self` by convention, it is retained here.

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def foo(self):
...     print 42
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> C.foo(c)
42
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, but I do not mean class member function.

Comment: So what. That's how it's called.

Answer (score 2):

That lambda is intended to be used similarly to a class method. The `self` is the instance of the class, pretty much the same as the `self` in any other method.